# Declaring a variable inside another variable

Tags: python

I need to declare a variable in Python in this manner, but it's not working out.

```
name = raw_input('Enter Name: ')

var1 = /dir_1/dir_2/% (name)

print (var1)
```

Expected Output :- `::/dir_1/dir_2/my custom entered name`.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What specific error are you getting?  What does "it's not working out" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
name =raw_input('Enter Name: ')
var1 = "/dir_1/dir_2/%s" %(name)
print (var1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the strings

```
name =raw_input('Enter Name: ')

var1 = '/dir_1/dir_2/' + name

print (var1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either concatenate the strings using `+`

```
>>> 'foo' + 'bar'
'foobar'
```

or you can use the `printf` style

```
>>> 'foo%s' %('bar')
'foobar'
```

I would suggest concatenation.

```
name = raw_input('Enter Name: ')

var1 = '/dir_1/dir_2/' + name

print (var1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an file name, it makes sense to join them using the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module. This will ensure that the current format for the file is used when the program is run on different OS's. In particular the function to use is [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

```
import os

name = raw_input('Enter Name: ')
var1 = os.path.normpath(os.path.join("/dir_1/dir_2", name))
print (var1)
```

On windows, you get something like:

```
\\dir_1\\dir_2\\name.txt
```

On Linux or unix based systems, this will return

```
/dir_1/dir_2/fname.txt
```

You might not need it for your case, but it is always nice to know this when you need code that should be portable.